# Search filter on encrypted data in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, encryption, filter

**Query Description:** Let say, I have a database table which stores all users' data in encrypted form. I have a functionality in which the Admin can search the user data. Now the problem is, Admin will enter the normal text in the textbox and I have to filter the user list(on every text change) according to the input of Admin. So meanwhile, I  have the bunch of data in encrypted form and I have to filter it on the basis of normal text that Admin enters.

What solution I came up till now is, I am decrypting all the data at first and then applying the filter. But I am curious to know, What if I have millions of records in my database then current way seems useless and inefficient.

Can anybody help me to search over encrypted data in the most efficient way?

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23908/how-to-search-a-mysql-database-with-encrypted-fields this may help you

Comment: encrypt the keyword

Comment: @mewc: encrypted value may differ on every text change.

Comment: How you are encrypting/decrypting data? Through AES_ENCRYPT/AES_DECRYPT or through php coding?

Comment: @NanaPartykar : Yes AES.

Comment: well if youre querying the full word - k@k.com -> k@k.com, it should be the same encrypted value

Comment: @mewc: if I want to filter Ronak Thakkar then I will write 'R' then 'o' then 'n' and so on. So in such case the encrypted value of 'Ronak Thakkar' and 'Ron' will differ from each other and 'Like query' will not work as there is partial search.

Comment: @RonakThakkar, Encrypting the whole database will not be a good idea, you should only encrypt essential data.

Comment: @RonakThakkar Maddy is correct. If you're doing entire db encryption as a goal, then you may have to either compromise or take the performance hit. The alternatives to that will be too verbose.

Comment: yes, make sense @mewc.

Comment: *"Can anybody help me to search over encrypted data in the most efficient way?"* Now you should consider upgrading to MySQL 8.0.13+ which adds in native tablespace [encryption](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-tablespace-encryption.html#innodb-tablespace-encryption-about) in the Advanced Encryption Standard (AES)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What solution I came up till now is, I am decrypting all the data at first and then applying the filter. But I am curious to know, What if I have millions of records in my database then current way seems useless and inefficient.

You're correct that this is not a scalable solution. If you want a deep dive into this problem, see: [Building Searchable Encrypted Databases with PHP and SQL](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/05/building-searchable-encrypted-databases-with-php-and-sql) .

What you want to do is:

1. Store encrypted data as-is, using **authenticated encryption**.
2. Store a **blind index** of the plaintext alongside the ciphertext.

   - A blind index can be `HMAC-SHA256(plaintext, separate_key)`
   - Sensitive values should use `sodium_crypto_pwhash()` or `hash_pbkdf2()` instead.
   - To save on space, truncate the blind index and treat it as a Bloom filter.

This gives you the best of both worlds: Data encryption that resists both passive and active attacks, but also allows for use in quick SELECT queries.

Update (2019-03-27): **Instead of building this yourself, check out [CipherSweet](https://paragonie.com/blog/2019/01/ciphersweet-searchable-encryption-doesn-t-have-be-bitter) which implements this design.**

Comment: Just because it uses AES doesn't mean it's using AES securely. AES is a block cipher, which isn't automatically secure. https://blog.filippo.io/the-ecb-penguin/ https://robertheaton.com/2013/07/29/padding-oracle-attack/

Comment: Your comment is non sequitur.

Comment: To be clear, if you HMAC-SHA256(plaintext, separate_key) alongside the ciphertext, then if the same plaintext is stored in two different rows, the attacker will be able to see that those two rows store the same value, right, even if the attacker won't be able to tell what the value is?