# Search Encrypted MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

Assume a MySQL database that has two fields: name and email. Also, assume that both fields need to be securely encrypted at rest due to privacy concerns. And assume that a third field contains a GUID that is the key used to encrypt the name/amail fields. (The third field value is used along with another value as the encryption key to reduce the possibility of having a 'master' key for all encryption. )

The application uses PHP (Version 7.4+) and MySQL.

How would you search the database for a plaintext value (name or email) when the data is encrypted at rest?

**Added**
Data will be encrypted with openssl_encrypt(). (And changed the above to MySQL.)

Comment: How exactly are you encrypting these values? It might also help to know if you're looking for LIKE matches or exact matches

Comment: Please explain why you think that storing the encryption key beside the ciphertext is in the least bit secure.

Comment: FYI: there is no such thing as a "MySQLi database". The software is called MySQL

Comment: as of the search itself - well, encrypt the input value and then search for the match

Comment: I don't see how PHP is relevant to this question. Your question is too broad in my opinion. How do you encrypt the values? Why can't you do as YCS suggested and search using the encrypted values? What have you tried already?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Search filter on encrypted data in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46659528/search-filter-on-encrypted-data-in-mysql)

Comment: PHP is relevant because that's what the application is coded in (web site). MySQL is relevant because that's where the data is stored. The YCS solution is helpful, but would seem to require a 'global' key that is used for every row in the table. Don't want to loop through the table and compare each encrypted cell using that row's key, so perhaps a 'global' key is the only way. Or is it?

Comment: You're dangerously close to understanding that this whole thing is a bad idea.

Comment: @Sammitch - which part is a bad idea? Perhaps storing the key as part of each row. So a global key would be better. But there's got to be a good secure way to store the global key? Or maybe a regularly scheduled job that would re-encrypt everything with a new key? Maybe the approach that CipherSweet uses? https://paragonie.com/blog/2019/01/ciphersweet-searchable-encryption-doesn-t-have-be-bitter

Comment: Encryption keys in a completely separate, much more secure system: https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/transit But also trying to keep low-level info like names and email addresses encrypted while also maintaining searchability is an exercise in futility.

Answer (score 2):

> How would you search the database for a plaintext value (name or email) when the data is encrypted at rest?

You can't do this *in general* with arbitrarily encrypted data, but a library like [CipherSweet](https://ciphersweet.paragonie.com) make this really easy.

The documentation should help you get the library installed.

To use it, you'll want to first [setup a `KeyProvider`](https://ciphersweet.paragonie.com/php/setup), then create an `EncryptedRow` object like so:

```
<?php
use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\BlindIndex;
use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\CipherSweet;
use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\CompoundIndex;
use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\EncryptedRow;
use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\Backend\FIPSCrypto;
use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\KeyProvider\StringProvider;

// Example key provider
$keyProvider = new StringProvider('4e1c44f87b4cdf21808762970b356891db180a9dd9850e7baf2a79ff3ab8a2fc');
// Setup the engine with a key provider. FIPSCrypto uses OpenSSL.
$engine = new CipherSweet($provider, new FIPSCrypto());

// EncryptedRow object setup:
$rowProcessor = (new EncryptedRow($engine, 'your_table_name_here'))
    ->addTextField('name')
    ->addTextField('email');
$rowProcessor->addBlindIndex(
    'name',
    new BlindIndex(
        'my_table__name_literal',
        16 /* See below */
    )
);
$rowProcessor->addBlindIndex(
    'email',
    new BlindIndex(
        'my_table__email_literal',
        16 /* See below */
    )
);
```

In this example, I added two blind indexes with a size of 16 bits each. This is a fudged number; you'll want to look at [blind index planning](https://ciphersweet.paragonie.com/php/blind-index-planning) for which values to use for guidance here.

Now you need to update your code when you read/write data into your MySQL database, using `$rowProcessor` to transparently encrypt/decrypt your data on-the-fly (in diff format):

```
 /** @var array<string, mixed> $inputValues */
 - $db->insert('your_table_name_here', $inputValues);
 + [$inputValuesSomeEncrypted, $indices] = $rowProcessor->prepareForStorage($inputValues);
 + // If you wish to store the blind indexes in the same table:
 +     $inputValuesSomeEncrypted['name_idx'] = $indices['my_table__name_literal'];
 +     $inputValuesSomeEncrypted['email_idx'] = $indices['my_table__email_literal'];
 + $db->insert('your_table_name_here', $inputValuesSomeEncrypted);
```

Next, you're going to need to tweak for your lookup logic.

```
- $rows = $db->lookup("name = ? OR email = ?", [$row['name'], $row['email']]);
+ $index1 = $rowProcessor->getBlindIndex('my_table__name_literal', $row);
+ $index2 = $rowProcessor->getBlindIndex('my_table__email_literal', $row);
+ $rowsWithCiphertext = $db->lookup("name_idx = ? OR email_idx = ?", [$index1, $index2]);
+
+ /* We need to post-process to eliminate coincidences in the blind index */
+ $rows = [];
+ foreach ($rowsWithCiphertext as $rowC) {
+     $decrypted = $rowProcessor->decryptRow($rowC);
+     if (!hash_equals($decrypted['name'], $row['name']) && !hash_equals($decrypted['email'], $row['email'])) {
+         continue;
+     }
+     $rows[] = $decrypted;
+ }
```

The *exact* code changes necessary will look different based on whatever your original code looks like. I'm just trying to demonstrate the structure here.

This will allow you to store encrypted data in your database *yet still* use the provided `name` or `email` parameters in the WHERE clause of your SQL queries (with a layer of abstraction).